The value of scale parameter σ in accelerated failure time model
my model follows Weibull distribution, my question about σ is when we could replace it with one and when we may consider it a scale parameter?

An accelerated failure time (AFT) model with outcome time $T$ takes the form
$$\log T = \alpha + \sigma W ,$$
with location parameter $\alpha$, $W$ a specified standard probability distribution, and $\sigma$ a scale factor.
For a Weibull model, $W$ follows a minimum extreme value distribution. If you set $\sigma=1$ in a Weibull model then it reduces to a simple exponential survival model. If you somehow know that your survival model is exponential then you could set $\sigma=1$. That seems risky in general, however. You can always fit the full Weibull model and examine whether $\sigma$ can be reliably distinguished from a value of 1. See this page for an example.

thanks alot EdM for your answer. In the research that I relied on "Using the Weibull Accelerated Failure Time Regression Model to Predict Time to Health Events ", it is assumed that the distribution of survival time is Weibull w~(x^' β,1/σ) and the error distribution follows Campbell G(0,1) when the model is log⁡(T)=x_i^' β+σε_i. Now may i suppose if the model is log⁡(T)=x_i^' β+ε_i, then the survival time follows Weibull w~(x^' β,1/σ) and the error follows Campbell G(0,1/σ), so is the model equal in both cases?

@AhmedNazih it depends on which parameterization of the Weibull you are using. I think you mean “Gumbel” instead of “Campbell” and then it depends on which Gumbel distribution you mean. Try drawing from the error distribution you have in mind, put it into the AFT formula with different location and scale parameters, and see which Weibull parameterization agrees.

Sorry, yes it's Gumbel, and thank you again
